# Discord.py how to make command Channel Specific

Tags: python, discord.py

So I've been trying to make certain commands channel specific. I can get the entire code to be that way but not certain commands.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    cmdChannel = bot.get_channel(780617002267967508)
    if message.channel.id == cmdChannel.id: 
        if ' ' in message.content:
            channel = message.channel
            await channel.send("Admin Commands <@287750380299747338>")
            return

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    cmdChannel = bot.get_channel(780599527664255003)
    if message.channel.id == cmdChannel.id: 
        if ' ' in message.content:
            channel = message.channel
            await channel.send("Admin Chat <@287750380299747338>")
            return
```

In my code, When I type a message with a space in my Admin Commands channel, I do not get a response from the bot, but it works perfectly fine in my Admin Chat channel. I want the bot to auto respond to messages with spaces in them for both channels, but have different responses based on the channel. For example:

I would type "Test Message" in admin commands, and it would return "Admin Commands @username"

I would type "Test Message" in admin chat, and it would return "Admin Chat @username"

What am I doing wrong? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice a few things in your code:

*First)* You **cannot** have multiple `on_message` events, then the code won't work.

*Second)* You check multiple times to see if the message is coming from a bot. Why? Once is enough.

*Third)* You don't need to query `message.channel.id` at all if you define the channel beforehand. Then simply `message.channel == DefinedChannel` is enough.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: # Check if the message comes from the bot
        return # Do nothing
    if ' ' in message.content: # Check if there is a space in the message
        admin_channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID) # Define our channel
        admin_commands = client.get_channel(ChannelID) # Define our second channel

        if message.channel == admin_channel: # Check if the message is in admin_channel
            await admin_channel.send(f"Admin Chat {message.author.mention}") # Mention the author
        elif message.channel == admin_commands: # Check if the message is in admin_commands
            await admin_commands.send(f"Admin Commands {message.author.mention}")
        else: # If the message is not in any of the two channels.
            return # Do nothing
```